# Scala - Split the nested json file into multiple json files along with its relation tree

Tags: json, scala, parsing, split

INPUT JSON :

```
{
   "Start":{
      "HInfo":{
         "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
         "SUType":"OnStup",
         "SModel":"Test",
         "Hostname":"Dummy",
         "SType":"Laptop",
         "Monitor":{
            "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
            "Index":0,
            "Type":"Lenovo",
            "VSData":"XYZVN"
         },
         "OS":"MSW-07",
         "LRTime":"2017-05-04",
         "Cables":[
            {
               "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
               "Index":0,
               "Name":"LC",
               "Status":"Installed"
            },
            {
               "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
               "Index":1,
               "Name":"WLSwitch",
               "Status":"Off"
            },
            {
               "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
               "Index":2,
               "Name":"WLAN",
               "Status":"Installed"
            }
         ],
         "NFan":{
            "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
            "Index":0
         },
         "Disk":[
            {
               "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
               "Index":0,
               "Name":"DISK0",
               "MKMdl":"THB",
               "BW_MB":694,
               "Partition":[
                  {
                     "HInfoID":"6ABCD1234",
                     "DGID":"ABCD1234",
                     "Index":0,
                     "Name":"Not Used",
                     "SM":500
                  },
                  {
                     "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
                     "DGID":"ABCD1234",
                     "Index":1,
                     "Name":"C:",
                     "SM":476438
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
               "Index":1,
               "Name":"DISK1",
               "MKMdl":"JFlsh",
               "BW_MB":0,
               "Partition":{
                  "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
                  "DGID":"ABCD1234",
                  "Index":0,
                  "Name":"E:",
                  "SM":7727
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Expected Output JSON Files :

1. {
   "obj_class":"HInfo",
   "obj_instance":"HInfo",
   "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo",
   "HInfo":{
     "HInfoID": "ABCD1234",
     "SUType":"OnStup",
     "SModel":"Test",
     "Hostname":"Dummy",
     "SType":"Laptop",
     "OS":"MSW-07",
     "LRTime":"2017-05-04"
     }}
2. {
     "obj_class":"Monitor",
     "obj_instance":"Monitor-1", 
     "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Monitor.Monitor-1",   //This Monitor-1 indicates that Monitor has only 1 instance
     "Monitor":{
        "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
        "Index":"0",
        "Type":"Lenovo",
        "VSData": "XYZVN"
     }}
3. {
    "obj_class":"Cables",
    "obj_instance":"Cables-1",
    "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Cables.Cables-1",
    "Cables":{
           "HInfoID": "ABCD1234",
           "Index":"0",
           "Name":"LC",
           "Status":"Installed"
        }}
4. {
    "obj_class":"Cables",
    "obj_instance":"Cables-2", 
    "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Cables.Cables-2",
    "Cables":{
           "HInfoID": "ABCD1234",
           "Index":"1",
           "Name":"WLSwitch",
           "Status":"Off"
        }}
5. {
   "obj_class":"Cables",
   "obj_instance":"Cables-3",
   "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Cables.Cables-3",
   "Cables":{
           "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
           "Index":"2",
           "Name":"WLAN",
           "Status":"Installed"
        }}
6. {
   "obj_class":"NFan",
   "obj_instance":"NFan-1",
   "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.NFan.NFan-1",
   "NFan":{
        "HInfoID": "ABCD1234",
        "Index": "0"
        }}
7. {
   "obj_class":"Disk",
   "obj_instance":"Disk-1",
   "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Disk.Disk-1",
   "Disk":{
   "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
   "Index":0,
   "Name":"DISK0",
   "MKMdl":"THB",
   "BW_MB":694
   }}
8. {
   "obj_class":"Partition",
   "obj_instance":"Partition-1",
   "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Disk.Disk-1.Partition.Partition-1",
   "Partition":{
   "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
   "DGID":"ABCD1234",
   "Index":0,
   "Name":"Not Used",
   "SM":500
   }}
9. {
   "obj_class":"Partition",
   "obj_instance":"Partition-2",
   "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Disk.Disk-1.Partition.Partition-2",
   "Partition":{
   "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
   "DGID":"ABCD1234",
   "Index":1,
   "Name":"C:",
   "SM":476438
   }}
10. {
    "obj_class":"Disk",
    "obj_instance":"Disk-2",
    "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Disk.Disk-2",
    "Disk":{
    "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
    "Index":1,
    "Name":"DISK1",
    "MKMdl":"JFlsh",
    "BW_MB":0
    }}
11. {
    "obj_class":"Partition",
    "obj_instance":"Partition-1",
    "relation_tree":"Start.HInfo.Disk.Disk-2.Partition.Partition-1",
    "Partition":{
    "HInfoID":"ABCD1234",
    "DGID":"ABCD1234",
    "Index":0,
    "Name":"E:",
    "SM":7727
    }}

Is there any generic way to split the nested json file into multiple json along with with its relation tree at very first line (without any hard coding of Node/Tag) using Scala? Instant help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah there's lots of way to do it. For example it would be pretty simple with the play framework to do this. But when I copypaste your json, it says that it's invalid json. Could you check to make sure you're really copy pasting valid json?

Comment: @AnamikaSingh what library do you want to use for json?

Comment: Also, is the structure always this one? Can it change?

Comment: Try with https://circe.github.io/circe/cursors.html

Comment: Not full answers, but these are initial structure that can help you. You need to go ahead from either one to (given a parsed input) produce your output: using circe https://gist.github.com/mfirry/c0100e9765b2a54a4a53e081bded9b3f or using play-json https://gist.github.com/mfirry/43698238af04808390ffde9c60ec2d36

Comment: Hi @mfirry, I really appreciate for your time and help, but the main issue is file size, the Actual file has minimum 25 Children and each one can have 1 to 200 tags, which can be a issue to provide by case class.... So I am looking for generic parser which can parse and get relation_tree along with splitting file without any hard coding of Node.

Comment: Are you sure about this possible performance issues? Also, give this a try: https://github.com/tethys-json/tethys

Comment: Hi @mfirry, can you please help in this below question :(  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772949/scala-apply-play-json-parse-method-on-spark-dataframe-json-column

Comment: Hi @GamingFelix , can you please help in this below question :(  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772949/scala-apply-play-json-parse-method-on-spark-dataframe-json-column